# JBoss migrating error

Tags: java, jboss6.x

I've got litle problem with migrating JBoss to 6.1.0 version
here is log of starting jboss:

```
16:21:26,091 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler] JBMETA-4: did not find any bean meta data for annotation bean ConferencesWebHelper, will create some
16:21:26,199 ERROR [org.jboss.weld.integration.instantiator.RedirectingBeanInstantiatorDeployer] Error during undeploy: vfs:///C:/Users/hgraczyk/Desktop/MAIN/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1327068853500/deploy/Main.ear/Conference.jar/: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not installed: org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/Main/Conference/ConferencesWebHelper
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.uninstall(AbstractController.java:790) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.uninstall(AbstractController.java:669) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.instantiator.deployer.BeanInstantiatorDeployerBase.undeploy(BeanInstantiatorDeployerBase.java:157) [:1.0.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.weld.integration.instantiator.RedirectingBeanInstantiatorDeployer.undeploy(RedirectingBeanInstantiatorDeployer.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.undeploy(DeployerWrapper.java:204) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doUndeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1862) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doUninstallParentLast(DeployersImpl.java:1769) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doUninstallParentLast(DeployersImpl.java:1749) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1507) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_11]

16:21:26,207 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///C:/Users/hgraczyk/Desktop/MAIN/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.x_Runtime_Server1327068853500/deploy/Main.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying Conference.jar: failed to initialize bean container 
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:194) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:60) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractSimpleVFSRealDeployer.java:56) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_11]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to initialize bean container 
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.<init>(EJBContainer.java:305) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.TimerServiceContainer.<init>(TimerServiceContainer.java:86) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.<init>(SessionContainer.java:125) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.<init>(SessionSpecContainer.java:111) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.<init>(StatefulContainer.java:124) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getStatefulContainer(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:311) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getContainers(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:217) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:759) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:710) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployUrl(Ejb3Deployment.java:692) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deploy(Ejb3Deployment.java:655) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:544) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:177) [:6.1.0.Final]
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:653) [:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:460) [:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:286) [:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222) [:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69) [:1.6.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3072) [:1.6.0_11]
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3029) [:1.6.0_11]
    at org.jboss.metadata.plugins.loader.reflection.AnnotatedElementMetaDataLoader.retrieveAnnotation(AnnotatedElementMetaDataLoader.java:113) [jboss-mdr.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.metadata.plugins.context.AbstractMetaDataContext.retrieveAnnotation(AbstractMetaDataContext.java:222) [jboss-mdr.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.metadata.plugins.context.AbstractMetaDataContext.retrieveAnnotation(AbstractMetaDataContext.java:228) [jboss-mdr.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.metadata.spi.retrieval.MetaDataRetrievalToMetaDataBridge.getAnnotation(MetaDataRetrievalToMetaDataBridge.java:63) [jboss-mdr.jar:2.2.0.SP1]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.metadata.annotation.AnnotationRepositoryToMetaData.resolveClassAnnotation(AnnotationRepositoryToMetaData.java:349) [:1.0.0]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.annotation.CachingAnnotationRepository.resolveClassAnnotation(CachingAnnotationRepository.java:300) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.aop.Advisor.resolveTypedAnnotation(Advisor.java:579) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.aop.Advisor.resolveAnnotation(Advisor.java:555) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.BeanContainer.getAnnotation(BeanContainer.java:97) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.getAnnotation(EJBContainer.java:1697) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.getVirtualMethods(SessionContainer.java:298) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.BeanContainer.getVirtualMethods(BeanContainer.java:186) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.getVirtualMethods(ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.java:64) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.createMethodTables(ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.java:51) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.aop.ClassAdvisor$1.run(ClassAdvisor.java:295) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_11]
    at org.jboss.aop.ClassAdvisor.attachClass(ClassAdvisor.java:276) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ManagedObjectAdvisor.initialize(ManagedObjectAdvisor.java:174) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.initialize(ExtendedManagedObjectAdvisor.java:70) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.AbstractContainer.initializeAdvisor(AbstractContainer.java:180) [:1.1.3]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.BeanContainer.initialize(BeanContainer.java:193) [:1.7.21]
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.<init>(EJBContainer.java:301) [:1.7.21]
    ... 55 more
```

plz help:
I'm using jdk1.6.17
maven 2.2.1
eclipse

---

here is source code:

source:

```
package webhelpers;

import webhelpers.EntityWrapper;
import webhelpers.WebHelperBase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Remove;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;


import org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator;
import org.hibernate.validator.InvalidValue;
import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Scope;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.datamodel.DataModel;
import org.jboss.seam.ejb.SeamInterceptor;
import org.jboss.seam.international.LocaleSelector;

import conference.ConferenceMailSenderLocal;
import conference.ConferenceMember;
import conference.ConferenceMemberFacadeLocal;
import conference.ConferenceParticipant;
import conference.ConferenceRoom;
import conference.ConferenceRoomFacadeLocal;
import security.UserBean;
import webhelpers.ContactsWebHelper.UserBeanWrapper;
import webhelpers.interfaces.ContactsWebHelperLocal;

@Stateful
@Name("conferencesWebHelper")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Interceptors(SeamInterceptor.class)
public class ConferencesWebHelper extends WebHelperBase implements ConferencesWebHelperLocal {

    @EJB
    private ConferenceRoomFacadeLocal conferenceRoomFacade;

    @EJB
    private ConferenceMailSenderLocal conferenceMailSender;

    @EJB
    private ConferenceMemberFacadeLocal conferenceMemberFacade;

//methods
```

Comment: We will need more information: was the "JBMETA-4: did not find any bean meta data for annotation bean ConferencesWebHelper" present in the old JBoss? What version was that? Can you show us the source code for ConferencesWebHelper?

Comment: this error has not present in old JBoss - it  was Version 5.1.0 GA

Comment: Can you reduce the ConferencesWebHelper file to the bare minimum still reproducing the error? Can you show us the source code for ConferencesWebHelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK answer was simple - like always in cases like this:

```
@Interceptors(SeamInterceptor.class)
```

the lib file, which got seaminterceptor wasnt add to *.ear content - adding lib solve problem
Ty for help